# Domino Designer - Error 501

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm running a Domino appication in Domino Designer and when I try to login via the url:

```
http://localhost/net/test118/test.nsf/loginform?openform
```

and click OK, the url redirects to [http://localhost/names.nsf?Login] and I get a 501 error:

```
HTTP Web Server: Function Not Implemented Exception
```

Any ideas, how I can login successfully?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use authentication when previewing on localhost.

Instead you can setup a Domino server on localhost if testing on a server is not an option.